Como puedo acceder a un campo de un array de arrays en php?
Estoy haciendo una aplicación de gestion de reciclaje donde estoy utilizando un $_SESSION para manejar los contenedores de reciclaje. Así lo tengo inicializado:
if (!isset($_SESSION['contenedores'])) {
  $_SESSION['contenedores'] = [
    'glass' => ['capacidad' => 10, 'actual' => 0],
    'organic' => ['capacidad' => 10, 'actual' => 0],
    'paper' => ['capacidad' => 10, 'actual' => 0],
    'plastic' => ['capacidad' => 10, 'actual' => 0]
  ];
}

Al intentar acceder a estos valores para mostrarlos, me encuentro con el siguiente error:
**
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in C:\Users\Tai\Documents\Developer\php\Reciclaje\indexTest.php on line 83
**
foreach ($_SESSION['contenedores'] as $tipo => $info) {
  echo '<p>Contenedor ' . ucfirst($tipo) . ': ' . $info . ' residuos</p>'; 
}


El problema está en el bucle foreach, en el echo, intentas imprimir $info directamente, pero $info es un array que contiene las claves capacidad y actual.  PHP no puede convertir un array en una cadena de texto para imprimirlo directamente.
//ECHO ERRONEO
foreach ($_SESSION['contenedores'] as $tipo => $info) {
    echo '<p>Contenedor ' . ucfirst($tipo) . ': ' . $info . ' residuos</p>'; 
}

Entonces debes modificarlo a lo siguiente:
foreach ($_SESSION['contenedores'] as $tipo => $info) {
  echo '<p>Contenedor ' . ucfirst($tipo) . ': ' . $info['actual'] . ' de ' . $info['capacidad'] . ' residuos</p>';
}

Ahora, mostrarás el tipo, seguido de ambos campos.

Lo he probado y me da el siguiente error dos veces: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int on line 83 (es la línea del echo).

Ok entonces hay algo diferente. Luego del IF que lo carga, imprime el session.

Espero que la línea 83 que dice el error , sea el for que has indicado tambien.

Ya esta! Cuando copié tu linea no copie el punto y coma del final. Gracias por ayudarme.

Aps, jaja un error lo comete cualquiera, Te agradezco si dejas el +1 tambien a la respuesta ;)
